# Delphi and sleep function

Tags: delphi, timer, sleep

I am having some issues regarding the sleep function. I have my application which executes an external command with some options:

```
str := 'C:\BERN52\MENU\menu.exe C:\BERN52\GPS\PAN\DAILY.INP C:\GPSUSER52\WORK\MENUAUX_DAILY.INP';
WinExec(Pansichar(str), SW_Shownormal);
```

After that when this process is finished I should kill it and continue with another things. I did the following:

```
Sleep(60000*StrToInt(Form1.Edit11.Text));
winexec('taskkill /F /IM menu.exe', SW_HIDE);
...
```

This sleeping time can be 4 minutes but also can be 2 days.
Of cause the main window going to the 'not responding' mode during this time. Could anyone suggest to me how to do this in a proper way?

Comment: Sure. Forget on Delphi application and create a task in task scheduler.

Comment: No way, should be in Delphi

Comment: Wait why are you forcefully killing the application (menu.exe) that you started? Or even better question. When? You claim that when some process is finished? What process? How do you know it is finished? These are all important information's that wee need.

Comment: This menu.exe is a software which compute GPS data. Computation time depend on number of this data. I have for scheduler - daily, weekly, monthly and yearly computation. I know how much time takes that processes. And the reason why I am killing this menu.exe - when it finished it should be closed before the next start.

Comment: Use `TTimer` component instead of `Sleep` function to schedule your action.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are estimating on when the process will be finished with its work based on how much data it needs to process. Hear my suggestion. DON'T! Why? Because there are to many things that could affect the time that is needed to process that data like some other process using large part of CPU power. So if you go and forcefully kill that application before it actually finishes its work you could cause data damage.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of that process?

Comment: Also process with menu.exe executable that is processing some GPS coordinates... Why does this smell to me like a possible malware?

Comment: There is no any problem with killing. I know exactly how much time I need for the computations. No source code at all for this

Comment: Funny))  Just type Bernese GNSS software and you will understand that this is not malware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `WinExec()` has been deprecated since 32bit Windows was first introduced.  Use `ShellExecuteEx()` or `CreateProcess()` instead.  This also provides you with a process handle that you can use to detect when the spawned process terminates, and you can also use it to kill the process if your timeout elapses.

```
type
  PHandle = ^THandle;

function StartProcess(const CmdLine: string; ProcessHandle: PHandle = nil): boolean;
var
  si: TStartupInfo;
  pi: TProcessInformation;
  str: string;
begin
  Result := False;
  if ProcessHandle <> nil then ProcessHandle^ := 0;

  str := CmdLine;
  {$IFDEF UNICODE}
  UniqueString(str);
  {$ENDIF}

  ZeroMemory(@si, sizeof(si));
  si.cbSize := sizeof(si);
  si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  si.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

  Result := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(str), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, si, pi);
  if Result then
  begin
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    if ProcessHandle <> nil then
      ProcessHandle^ := pi.hProcess
    else
      CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
  end;
end;
```

If you absolutely must block your calling code while waiting, use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` in a loop so you can still service the message queue:

```
procedure TForm1.Start;
var
  hProcess: THandle;
  Timeout, StartTicks, Elapsed, Ret: DWORD;
begin
  Timeout := 60000 * StrToInt(Edit11.Text);

  if StartProcess('C:\BERN52\MENU\menu.exe C:\BERN52\GPS\PAN\DAILY.INP C:\GPSUSER52\WORK\MENUAUX_DAILY.INP', @hProcess) then
  try
    repeat
      StartTicks := GetTickCount;
      Ret := MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, hProcess, False, Timeout, QS_ALLINPUT);
      if Ret <> (WAIT_OBJECT_0+1) then Break;
      Application.ProcessMessages;
      Elapsed := GetTickCount - StartTicks;
      if Elapsed <= Timeout then
        Dec(Timeout, Elapsed)
      else
        Timeout := 0;
    until False;
    if Ret <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
      TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);
  finally
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
  end;
end;
```

Otherwise, use a `TTimer` so the main message loop is not blocked:

```
var
  hProcess: THandle = 0;

procedure TForm1.Start;
begin
  Timer1.Active := False;
  if StartProcess('C:\BERN52\MENU\menu.exe C:\BERN52\GPS\PAN\DAILY.INP C:\GPSUSER52\WORK\MENUAUX_DAILY.INP', @hProcess) then
  begin
    Timer1.Tag := StrToInt(Edit11.Text);
    Timer1.Interval := 1000;
    Timer1.Active := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ret: DWORD;
begin
  Ret := WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 0);
  if Ret = WAIT_TIMEOUT then
  begin
    Timer1.Tag := Timer1.Tag - 1;
    if Timer1.Tag > 0 then
      Exit;
  end;
  if Ret <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
    TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);
  CloseHandle(hProcess);
  hProcess := 0;
  Timer1.Active := False;
end;
```

Otherwise, use a worker thread instead of a timer:

```
type
  TStartProcessThread = class(TThread)
  private
    fCmdLine: string;
    fTimeout: DWORD;
    fTermEvent: THandle;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const CmdLine; Timeout: DWORD);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Stop;
  end;

function StartProcess(const CmdLine: string; ProcessHandle: PHandle = nil): boolean;
begin
  // as shown above...
end;

constructor TStartProcessThread.Create(const CmdLine; Timeout: DWORD);
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  fTermEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
  if fTermEvent = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  fCmdLine := CmdLine;
  fTimeout := Timeout;
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

destructor TStartProcessThread.Destroy;
begin
  if fTermEvent <> 0 then CloseHandle(fTermEvent);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TStartProcessThread.Stop;
begin
  Terminate;
  SetEvent(hTermEvent);
end;

procedure TStartProcessThread.Execute;
var
  H: array[0..1] of THandle;
begin
  if not StartProcess(fCmdLine, @H[0]) then Exit;
  H[1] := fTermEvent;

  if WaitForMultipleObjects(2, PWOHandleArray(@H), False, INFINITE) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
    TerminateProcess(H[0], 0);

  CloseHandle(H[0]);
end;

var
  Thread: TStartProcessThread = nil;

procedure TForm1.Start;
begin
  Thread := TStartProcessThread.Create('C:\BERN52\MENU\menu.exe C:\BERN52\GPS\PAN\DAILY.INP C:\GPSUSER52\WORK\MENUAUX_DAILY.INP', 60000 * StrToInt(Edit11.Text));
  Thread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
  Thread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Thread := nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if Thread <> nil then
  begin
    Thread.OnTerminate := nil;
    Thread.Stop;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Nothing happens. The thread is gone.  But the only way to abort `WaitForSingleObject()` without signaling the object it is waiting on is to forcibly terminate the thread using `TerminateThread()` or `TerminateProcess()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `Sleep` in the UI thread, then the UI thread is no longer able to service its message queue. The *not responding* message is inevitable. The clear conclusion from this is that you must not call `Sleep` in the UI thread.

You could spin up another thread and put your `Sleep` call there. When that call to `Sleep` returns you can then do whatever needs to be done.

Some other comments:

1. Sleeping for such a long time is usually not the best solution to any problem. Perhaps you want to schedule a task. Or perhaps you'd be better having a periodic *pulse* in your program that checked whether the timeout had expired.
2. `Winexec` has been deprecated since 32 bit Windows was released, over 20 years. Use `CreateProcess` to start an external process.
3. If you wish to kill a process, use `TerminateProcess`.
4. Termination seems a little drastic. Isn't there any other way for you to persuade this other program to stop?

Comment: Thanks. I can close this software by pushing the button but I need fully automated process.

Comment: If the other process has a GUI, you should post a `WM_QUIT` message to it so it can break its message loops and exit cleanly.

Comment: Thank you David! I did it according to your recommendations. Now its working well.